# Creating Triangle with UIBezierPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to understand how to create a triangle shape with Swift. I found this code that creates a triangle.

```
class TriangleLayer: CAShapeLayer {

  let innerPadding: CGFloat = 30.0  

  override init() {
    super.init()
    fillColor = Colors.red.CGColor
    strokeColor = Colors.red.CGColor
    lineWidth = 7.0
    lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    path = trianglePathSmall.CGPath
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  var trianglePathSmall: UIBezierPath {
     let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
     trianglePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 5.0 + innerPadding, y: 95.0))     // #1
     trianglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 12.5 + innerPadding)) // #2
     trianglePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 95.0 - innerPadding, y: 95.0)) // #3
     trianglePath.closePath()
     return trianglePath
 }
```

And this code creates a shape like this
[image] in the middle of the screen.

I tried to tweak and play around with it to understand how it works; however, at this point I realised that I got lost with the logic quite a bit. I placed the CGPoints of above triangle on an x-y axis in my head and it seems something like:

```
 #1 x:35, y:95          #3 x:65, y:95
           #2 x:50, y: 42.5
```

But the triangle is created upside-down if I place the dots on the x-y axis.

[image]

What I want to achieve is what the axis tells, and I want to achieve..

```
         .   .                                .
                 <like this.   not this> 
           .                                .   .
```

---

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-SW1 This is Apple's documentation for drawing in 2 dimensions.

Comment: 0,0 is in the upper left corner so the Y-axis increment downwards.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have the axes in your head upside down. The coordinate system starts at 0,0 and extends right in X and down in Y.

So your points are really:

```
           #2 x:50, y: 42.5 
 #1 x:35, y:95          #3 x:65, y:95
```

to get your desired triangle you'd have something like:

```
 #1 x:35, y:95          #3 x:65, y:95
           #2 x:50, y: 147.5
```

Answer (score 2):

[Result triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDrd2.png)

Code in swift5

```
//TriangleView

extension UIView {

    func setRightTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width //you can use triangleView.frame.size.height
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setLeftTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setUpTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
     let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:heightWidth))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setDownTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.***

The easiest way of doing it by using AutoLayout:

1. Open your Storyboard and drag a `UIView` in `UIViewController`, position it and set the size as you wish (that's the place where the triangle will be). Set the view background to be transparent.
2. Create a new class, you can name it however you want (I named mine `TriangleView`). This will be the content of that class:

`class TriangleView: UIView {`

```
//    predefined variables that can be changed
    var startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    var endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    var firstGradientColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    var secondGradientColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue

    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let height = self.layer.frame.size.height
        let width = self.layer.frame.size.width

//        draw the triangle 
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
        path.close()

//        draw the triangle 'upside down'
//        let path = UIBezierPath()
//        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
//        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: 0))
//        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height))
//        path.close()

//        add path to layer
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

//        Add the gradient for the view background if needed
        gradient.colors = [firstGradientColor.cgColor, secondGradiendColor.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = startPoint
        gradient.endPoint = endPoint
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.mask = shapeLayer

        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

3. Go to your `Storyboard`, select the `UIView` and in `Identity Inspector` write the class name `TriangleView`
4. Enjoy your triangle! :)